# How can i fix filter and pagination to work

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-views, pagination

I am trying to filter items based on prince range and then paginate the result. I have gone through the documentation but still doesnt work. i have tried all the logic i could come up with but not working still.

The search shows the first page items but once i click on the subsequent pages, it doesnt display anything. If i use `if request.Method==''POST:"`, It shows: `variable used before assignment`.

I also tried using `if request.method =="GET"` but it still didn't work.
The search shows the first page items but once i click on the subsequent pages, it doesn't display anything.

model.py

```
    class Property(models.Model):
        name =models.CharField(max_length=200) 
        price = models.IntegerField(default=1000)
        bedroom = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        bathroom =models.IntegerField(default=1)
        status =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True) 
        sqft =models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True) 
        acre =models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,null=True) 
        Location = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True) 
        describe =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
        img = CloudinaryField(blank=True,null=True)
       
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name 
    
        class Meta:
            #db_table='accommodation' 
    
            verbose_name_plural='Property'
```

view.py - i dont know if there's an error here because it doesn't show any result apart from the first page

```
    def availableProperty(request):
        #if request.method =="POST":
    
        name =request.POST.get('property')
        minpay =request.POST.get('min-price')
        maxpay =request.POST.get('max-price')
    
        if name == 'all':
          #getiing the model property and filtering the price range
            result= Property.objects.filter(price__range=(minpay, 
            maxpay))#.order_by('-price')
    
        else:
            result= Property.objects.filter(price__range=(minpay, 
             maxpay),name=name)#.order_by('-price')
    
        
        p = Paginator(result,5)
        number = request.GET.get('page') 
        resultobj = p.get_page(number)
            
            # here ,i used try excerpt yet it didn't work
         #   try:
                #resultobj = p.page(number)
          #      resultobj = p.get_page(request.GET.get('page'))
    
            
           # except PageNotAnInteger:
            #            resultobj = p.get_page(1)
           # except EmptyPage:
    
          #      resultobj = p.get_page(p.num_pages)   
    
        context ={
                'resultobj':resultobj
            }
        return render(request, 'property_info.html',context)
```

template - property_info.html

```
    {% extends 'index.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
    
    
    
    <style>
    
        .want_to_buy{
            display: none;
        }
        .display{
            display: none;
        }
        .property-search{
            display: none;
        }
        .featured{
            display: none;
        }
    
    
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-top: 25px;
    }
    
    .flex-item-left {
      flex: 50%;
    }
    
    .flex-item-right {
      flex: 50%;
    }
    .card-image{
        width: 300px;
        height: 280px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .card-image img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .property-information{
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .property-address h2{
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
      
        color: #0076AD;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .property-information h3{
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color: #333;
    
    }
    .property-information span{
        color: green;
    }
    .right{
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
    .search-result{
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    .search-section .description{
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #333;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    .btn-groupy{
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: 20;
        right: -50px;
       
        
    }
    .contar{
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    
    /* Responsive layout - makes a one column layout instead of a two-column layout */
    @media (max-width: 800px) {
      .flex-item-right, .flex-item-left {
        flex: 100%;
      }
    }
        </style>
       
      
    
    
    
    
    <div class="search-section">
        
        <h1 class="search-result">Search result</h1>
    
       {% for result in resultobj %} 
    <div class="flex-container">
        
       
      <div>
      
    
        <div class="property-flex">
            
            <a href="">
            <div class="card-image ">
                <img src="{{ result.img.url }}" alt="">
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <div class="property-information">
             <a href="">
                <div class="property-address">
                    <h2>{{result.Location }}</h2>
                </div>
             </a>
              <div class="property-information">
                  <h3>Price:<span>${{result.price }}</span></h3>
                  <h3>bedroom:{{result.bedroom }}</h3>
                  <h3>bathroom:{{result.bathroom }}</h3>
                  <h3>Sqft:{{result.sqft }}</h3>
                  <h3>Acres:{{result.acre}}</h3>
                  <h3>SubdivisionSee Legal Description Below.</h3>
                 
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="property-information">
          <h3 class="right">Listing ID50044316
            PBMLS-RETS</h3>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <h3 class="description"> {{result.describe }}</h3>
    <div class="contar">
    <div class="btn-groupy " role="group" aria-label="Basic mixed styles example">
        <a href="" type="button" class="btn btnb btn-danger">View pictures</a>
        <a href="" type="button" class="btn btnb btn-warning">Visual Tour</a>
        <a href="" type="button" class="btn btnb btn-success">Add To Favourite</a>
        <a href="" type="button" class="btn btnb btn-dark">View Details</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    {% if resultobj.has_other_pages %}
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if resultobj.has_previous %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ resultobj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in resultobj.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if resultobj.number == i %}
            <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if resultobj.has_next %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ resultobj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% endblock %}
    
    # urls.py 
      path('property_search/' ,views.availableProperty,name='property_search')
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using CBV?

Comment: i dont understand CBV.What does it mean and how can i use it?

Comment: It's Class Based Views, they are making writing views much easier, it's best if you check Django Docs on that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: i used Class based View too.pagination works well but filtering and paginating same time is not working.May be my logic is wrong. Help me out if you can

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution for me has been using javascript instead of django/python, since I am using:

```
<a class="page-link" data-href="?page={{items.paginator.num_pages}}" href="?page={{items.paginator.num_pages}}">Last</a>
```

I added a javascript to detect if there is any filter and add &page="page number" instead of ?page="pagenumber".

```
<script>
    // pagination
    let pag = document.querySelectorAll('a.page-link')
    console.log(pag.length)
    let url = window.location

    if (url.href.includes("?csrfmiddlewaretoken"))
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < pag.length; i++)
        {
            pag[i].href = url.search + pag[i].getAttribute("data-href").replace("?","&")
            console.log(pag[i].getAttribute("data-href"))
        }
    } else {
        console.log("not included")
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps.